# Spring MVC + Session Conversation (multiple tabs) + Spring Security with CSRF + Thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

In previous versions of Spring + Spring security, when I didnt use the built in CSFR, it was easy to add session conversation support (for supporting multiple "edit" tabs), using the techniques described at https://github.com/duckranger/Spring-MVC-conversation, specifically implementing a `RequestDataValueProcessor`

however, now that we use spring boot and all it's auto configure goodness, `CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor` now implements `RequestDataValueProcessor`

if I add my own `RequestDataValueProcessor` implemenation, it never gets used.

Can anyone point me in the right direction so that I can use both `CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor` and my `RequestDataValueProcessor`

I assume I would need to create a composite `RequestDataValueProcessor`, or can you have multiple `RequestDataValueProcessor` implemenations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thought I would share what I did to get this working.
I needed a solution, and I just couldn't get my own RequestDataValueProcessor to be used by Thymeleaf, even though the bean was created in my configuration correctly.

Note: I am aware that this is quite a hack, but it is pretty interesting at the same time.

The Solution: AspectJ.....

```
@Aspect
public class SessionConversationAspect {

    private final ConversationIdRequestProcessor conversationIdRequestProcessor;

    public SessionConversationAspect() {
        this.conversationIdRequestProcessor = new ConversationIdRequestProcessor();
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(* org.springframework.security.web.servlet.support.csrf.CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.getExtraHiddenFields(..) ) && args(request) )")
    protected void getExtraHiddenFields(HttpServletRequest request) {
    }

    @AfterReturning(
            pointcut = "getExtraHiddenFields(request)",
            returning = "hiddenFields"
    )
    protected void addExtraHiddenFields(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, String> hiddenFields) {
        Map<String, String> extraFields = conversationIdRequestProcessor.getExtraHiddenFields(request);
        hiddenFields.putAll(extraFields);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this very problem by a small modification to the duckranger solution. I wedged a call to a ScrfRequestDataValueProcessor into the getExtraHiddenFields method.

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> getExtraHiddenFields(HttpServletRequest request) {
    CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor csrfRDVP = new CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor();
    Map<String, String> hiddenFields = csrfRDVP.getExtraHiddenFields(request);

    if (request.getAttribute(ConversationalSessionAttributeStore.CID_FIELD) != null) {
        hiddenFields.put(ConversationalSessionAttributeStore.CID_FIELD,
        request.getAttribute(ConversationalSessionAttributeStore.CID_FIELD).toString());
    }

    return hiddenFields;
}
```

Just implemented this today and have barely started user testing so USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.

I can't help but think there's a better way but this seems to do the trick.